# how to add kafka with jupyter notebook

Tags: jar, pyspark

I am trying to connect kafka with python (jupyter notebook) after adding jar file my code is  not running and giving error.can you please tell me how can i connect kafka with any of python IDE like pycharm and jupyter notebook

I tried to run it in jupter notebook it is a simply word count program and data is not coming in jupyter notebook .then i tried to submit python script  with the  command line still it is showing some error

bin/spark-submit --jars --master spark://Ubuntu:7077 /home/user/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.3.jar

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR spark://Ubuntu:7077 with URI spark. Please specify a class through --class.
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$1.(SparkSubmit.scala:911)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:911)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)